# Twitter4j how to get tweets from certain time

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

```
Query query = new Query("Apple");
     query.lang("en");
     query.setCount(100);
     query.setSince("2018-12-03");
     query.setUntil("2018-12-04");
     QueryResult result = twitter.search(query);
     SentiWordNetDemoCode sentiwordnet = new SentiWordNetDemoCode();
     for (Status tweet : result.getTweets()){
        System.out.println(tweet.getCreatedAt());
     }
```

When testing this, all the tweets are from 7:59 SRET. Is there any way to get a tweet from a time other than this?

Answer (score 0):

According to the API reference on twitter, there are some restrictions to the query. There is no (more) `since` parameter, only a `since_id` which takes a status id. Then you can only search in the last 7 days. So the `until` field should not be older than that.

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/api-reference/get-search-tweets.html